# Cron job won't start again after I stopped it?

Tags: bash, cron

I wrote a script to run constantly on startup. If for whatever reason the script were to fail, I wrote a second script to check if it has failed, and if so, run the first script again. I then set this second script as a cronjob to run every minute so that it is constantly checking if the first script is alive.

So to test this, I reboot my system. I can see in htop that the first script is running from start up as expected. Good. I kill the process to test the second script. Sure enough, the second script starts the first script again. Still good. I then kill *this* process, but the second script won't run again now. It still updates a txt file when I manually start the first script, but the second script just doesn't start the first script like it's supposed to. Is it because I killed the cronjob? Restarting the cron service doesn't fix anything though, so I don't know why my second script isn't running again at all.

First script:

```
#!/bin/bash
stamp=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)
timeout 10d tcpdump -i eth0 -s 96 -z gzip -C 10 -w /home/user/Documents/${stamp}
```

Second script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "not running" > /home/working.txt
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep tcpdump.sh | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
echo "tcpdump is running!!!" > /home/working.txt

else
/usr/local/bin/tcpdump.sh start
fi
```

Any help?

Comment: Mmmm... you have 2 scripts, neither of which we can see, and you are hoping we can tell you what's wrong with one or both of them? Please post a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example so that we can assist you better. Click `edit` under your post, paste in your code, then select it with the mouse and click the formatting button labelled `{}` to format it as code.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Better?

Comment: Yes, but we still can't see your `crontab` entry either.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off running a simple for loop as the main script, and that kicks off the tcpdump script in the background, so something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -q tcpdump; then
        : tcpdump running OK
    else
        # tcpdump not running - start it off
        nohup /usr/local/bin/firstscript.sh start &
    fi
    sleep 30
done
```

This checks that "tcpdump.sh" is in the output of the "ps -ef" command - if it is, then do nothing (note that you must have an actual command between the "then" and "else" - the ":" command, which just takes it s arguments and ignores them, is sufficient). If it isn't running, start the first script in the background. Then sleep 30 seconds and check again. (Yes, I could have inverted the test so that I didn't need an empty "then" arm, but it would have made the code less obvious)

You put this script as the one which starts at boot time.

Edit: Do you really want to check for "tcpdump.sh"? Is that what the first script is actually called? Assuming that you actually want to check for the tcpdump program, you could use:

```
if pgrep tcpdump; then
```

Comment: Sorry, I was making some changes and forgot to revert it. Yes the first script is tcpdump.sh, I've reflected that in the code now. Thanks, I'll try this and see what happens.